# How to fix KeyError in ThreadPoolExecutor after all async code executed normally?

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio

I use some async code in my django appliction, one particular view with async call keeps returning me this Error. The most strange part is that I printed result of executing async code in console and it seems like it executed without errors... So i don't know where this bug comes from and how to debug it?

```
Exception inside application: <Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0, started daemon 140193531164416)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 44, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/asgi.py", line 161, in __call__
    response = await self.get_response_async(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 150, in get_response_async
    response = await self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 448, in __call__
    ret = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 442, in wait_for
    return await fut
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 495, in thread_handler
    del self.launch_map[current_thread]
KeyError: <Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0, started daemon 140193531164416)>
```

Comment: I tried to use my wizard orb to find out bug in your code, but no luck... Looks like you still have to provide [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)